# My External CSS Stylesheet with displays only 1-column, with Internal stylesheet it displays 2-columns

Tags: css

Using proporpational-based grids I get a 2-column display when I use the Internal Stylesheet. However when I use the External stylesheet I get only a 1-column display.

How do I get the External Stylesheet to display 2-column layout?

Here is my code with both External and Internal stylesheet coding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>DUCK</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="temp.css" type="text/css"> 

<style>
* {   box-sizing: border-box;    }
.row  {   width: 100%; }
img   {   width: 100%; }
.desc {  font-variant: small-caps; }

/********** Large devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.col-lg-6  {  float: left;  border: 2px solid green }
.col-lg-6  {  width: 50%;   }
}

/********** Medium devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
.col-md-12 {  float: left;  border: 2px solid green}
.col-md-12 {  width: 100%;  }
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Responsive Layout</h1>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"> 
 <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/rubber-duck-21077756.jpg"  <div
  class="desc">duck</div>  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"> 
 <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/rubber-duck-21077756.jpg"  <div
  class="desc">duck</div>  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"> 
 <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/rubber-duck-21077756.jpg"  <div
  class="desc">duck</div>  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"> 
 <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/rubber-duck-21077756.jpg"  <div
  class="desc">duck</div>  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```